# Regular Expression with Two Names: One With Middle Initial and One Without

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re, python-regex

I'm attempting to identify the names in this string, using regex (https://regex101.com).

Example text:

```
Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432
```

What I've tried so far only seems to work for names without a middle initial:

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+) ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)
```

Note: Phone Numbers are random keystrokes.  Please don't try calling them.

Here's an example of python code using the re package:

```
import re
strr = 'Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432'

def gimmethenamesdammit(strr):
    regex = re.compile("([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+) ([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)")
    print(regex.findall(strr))

gimmethenamesdammit(strr)
```

To sum things up, please modify the regular expression above to highlight both the names `Elon R. Musk` and `Jeff Bezos`

Desired python output when running `gimmethenamesdammit(strr)`:

```
gimmethenamesdammit(strr)

[('Elon', 'R.', 'Musk'), ('Jeff', 'Bezos')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex expression solves the issue:

```
import re

strr = 'Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432'

regex = r"[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]?\w+"

POCs = re.findall(regex, strr)

f"{POCs[0]}, {POCs[-1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `\b([^\s*][a-zA-Z_\.\s]+)\b`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7ul1pQ/1

1. `\b...\b` -- [word boundary](https://Word%20Boundaries)
2. `[^\s*][a-zA-Z_\.\s]+` -- text with letters, dots and spaces
3. `()` -- [captured group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: If I run that with this code: ```import re
strrr = 'Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432'

def gimmethenamesdammit(strr):
    regex = re.compile("\b([^\s*][a-zA-Z_\.\s]+)\b")
    print(regex.findall(strrr))

gimmethenamesdammit(strrr)``` I get an empty list: ```[]``` @star67

Comment: because you need to escape the escaping character "\" in python string: `re.compile("\\b([^\s*][a-zA-Z_\.\s]+)\\b")`

Comment: I see, thanks! I noticed the output is ```['Elon R. Musk', 'Jeff Bezos']```, which is close, but looking for ```[('Elon', 'R.', 'Musk'), ('Jeff', 'Bezos')]```.  Is this possible? @star67

Comment: @getintoityuh why don't split by space? the output format looks very specific to your problem

Comment: Emails instead of phone numbers could be listed in the future, or perhaps addresses.  If I add any other regular character text to the demo, it groups those as well.  Example: ```import re
strrrr = 'Elon R. Musk (245)436-7956 elonmust@tesla.com Jeff Bezos (235)231-3432 bezosjeffreyallen@bezos.net'

def gimmethenamesdammit(strr):
    regex = re.compile("\\b([^\s*][a-zA-Z_\.\s]+)\\b")
    print(regex.findall(strrrr))

gimmethenamesdammit(strrrr)``` generates ```['Elon R. Musk', 'elonmust', '@tesla.com Jeff Bezos', 'bezosjeffreyallen', '@bezos.net']``` @star67.

Comment: I could pose this as a new question, I suppose, but regardless my desired output list in the question was ```[('Elon', 'R.', 'Musk'), ('Jeff', 'Bezos')]``` @star67

Comment: ```r"[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]?\w+"``` is the best for this @star67